# Can't turn webelement into integer using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
steps = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="current_steps"]')
steps_Num = int(steps)
```

it keeps returning the error That int() function cant be used on webelement can only be used on strings , etc.

Comment: Is the web element a form field? Can you [edit] your question and include the HTML for the web element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`steps` is indeed a webelement and cannot be converted to `int`. To access the text inside the element, you need to be using:

```py
steps = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="current_steps"]')
steps_Num = int(steps.text)
```

Comment: i did that but still get the same problem (at first it seemed to work but then when i ran it through a while loop it stopped working)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could mention the exact error

Comment: i dont know what happened it now works its acting very wierd